# Possible to reuse first argument of BASH line in the same line?

Tags: bash, command-line, arguments, variable-substitution

I do this in BASH

```
echo test "$1"
```

..expecting to get..

```
test test
```

..but I get..

```
test
```

Is this something possible to do? It would make my life easier since having a list files I could do something like `mv a/b/test.py proj_copy/$1`

Comment: `echo test{,}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use history expansion

```
$ echo test !#:^
echo test test
test test

$ echo a/b/test.py proj_copy/!#:^
echo a/b/test.py proj_copy/a/b/test.py
a/b/test.py proj_copy/a/b/test.py
```

> !#
>   The entire command line typed so far.
>
> :^
>     The first argument

---

You could also use brace expansion

```
$echo test{,}
test test

$echo {,proj_copy}/a/b/test.py
/a/b/test.py proj_copy/a/b/test.py
```